# Serve xlsx file from MongoDB binary using Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, binary

I have some Excel documents (xlsx) saved in MongoDB in binary. I would like node.js to retrieve a file from the database when a user navigates to a url and serve the file for the user to download. I'm successfully downloading *a* file, but I'm getting an error from Excel when trying to open the file:

*"Excel cannot open the file '5beec8ef3cf3e70b5ce8972e.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file."*

The file is also saving with 0 bytes. I think I am not correctly converting the data from MongoDB before trying to create the buffer. Here's my script:

```
app.get('//downloadReport/:id', (req, res) => {
    dbo = db.db('test');
    dbo.collection("reports").findOne(
        {'_id': mongodb.ObjectId(req.params.id)}
    ).then(doc => {

        console.log('type of doc.file: ' + typeof doc.file);
        // returns:
        // type of doc.file: object

        console.log(doc.file);
        // returns:
        // Binary {
        //   _bsontype: 'Binary',
        //   sub_type: 0,
        //   position: 1146504,
        //   buffer: <Buffer 50 4b 03 04 14 00 00 00 08 00 12 66 6f 4d f8 64 19 ... > }


        res.writeHead(200, [['Content-Type',  'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet']]);

        // This one doesn't work
        // res.end(doc.file, 'binary');
        // returns:
        // TypeError: First argument must be a string or Buffer

        res.end(new Buffer(doc.file, 'binary') );
    });
});
```

I've tried drilling down to `doc.file.Binary.buffer`, but I get an error saying `doc.file.Binary` is not defined.

I also want the file to download with the correct file name. I've tried adding this to `writeHead`:

```
['Content-disposition', 'filename=' + doc.filename]
```

but I get an error in Chrome: `ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION`

Anyone know how to make this work? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I just needed to use `doc.file.buffer` and put double quotes (`"`) around the filename.

I found the buffer answer here: [How to save file in Mongodb using Node.js](https://medium.com/@dineshuthakota/how-to-save-file-in-mongodb-using-node-js-1a9d09b019c1)

```
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
      'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="' + doc.filename + '"'
    });

    res.end(new Buffer(doc.file.buffer, 'binary') );
```

Comment: The new Buffer declaration is now marked as deprecated
Now you can use Buffer.alloc(number) or Buffer.from(string)